# SIGALARM giving constant value if seconds in negetive

Tags: linux

```
achul@achul:~/chennai/linux/SM_practise$ cat doubt.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
main()
{
    int ret;
    printf("\nhello x : if i'm give -ve alarm second then what it will return \n");
    ret=alarm(-5);
    printf("ret=%d\n",ret);//
    ret=alarm(8);
    printf("ret=%d\n",ret);// why exactly 2G
    while(1);
}
```

since alarm 1st parameter is unsigned int thats why may be its converting -5 to unsigned value . if i'm giving alarm of any negative value in second alarm its returning 2147483647 only ? why is that so .. any theory ?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by giving it -5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are specifying 4+ billion (4,294,967,296 - 5) seconds—which is about 136 years—for the delay.

That is what happens when a signed int is promoted to an `unsigned int`.  The declaration for `alarm()` is:

```
unsigned int alarm (unsigned int seconds);
```

`-5` as a 32-bit value is 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 in [twos-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (which is what *all* modern CPUs use) binary.

Regarding that bit pattern as an unsigned int makes its value be 4,294,967,291.